# How-to turn off mobile admin mode?

Tags: admin

I want to permanently turn off the mobile admin interface, which I find incredibly annoying. What file do I need to edit to turn off the mobile admin interface?

This question is not about WordPress themes.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to edit /wp-admin/admin-header.php and search for "device-width" and change it to something like this:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">`

This allows you to see the unadulterated WordPress admin interface on your tablet or phone. No more jumbo-size letters.

Comment: This might solve your issue, but it is really a very bad idea to modify core code. Your changes will be lost if you upgrade wordpress

Comment: What choice do I have? Is there a better solution?